# Problem with polyglossia with "babelshorthands" enabled and minted: .out.pyg file is not generated anymore

Tags: minted, polyglossia

Since some years I'm working with `polyglossia` and the `minted` package in combination with XeLaTeX and English texts without any problems. Now I had to write a document in German with some code, so I wanted to use `polyglossia` with German as main language and `babelshorthands` enabled together with `minted`. When I try to compile this document, the `.out.pyg` file is not generated and XeLaTeX throws an error.

This issue disappears if I disable `babelshorthands`.

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{python}
        x = 1
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The code above throws the aforementioned error. Now remove `babelshorthands=true` as option from the `\setmainlanguage` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{python}
        x = 1
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The document should now compile without any errors.

Is this a bug in `polyglossia`/`minted` or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Loading `minted` before `polyglossia` seems to help.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, that solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `babel` and `polyglossia` (which might be considered as a bug, probably): while the former makes shorthand characters active at `\begin{document}`, `polyglossia` makes them active immediately.

Since the definition of the internal macro `\minted@pygmentize` contains `"`, a problem arises.

Solution: load `minted` before `polyglossia`.